# consecutive days isn't working properly

Tags: support, consecutive-days

For the past day's I have been logging on every day on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/
Today I logged in again only to find out my consecutive days were reset back to 1.

My other accounts didn't reset.

How is this possible? I am 100% sure I was logged yesterday.

Comment: Adjust your "sureness" for UTC and try again, please.

Comment: Also just logging in isn't sufficient to count as activity for that counter.

Comment: A Stack Exchange day is a UTC day. If you have not visited in a UTC day (**not** local time), it will be reset as you described.

Comment: @Mat sorry, I described that poorly. it's not just logging

Comment: @Oded This could be possible(and probably is the reason), even though I login multiple times a day.

Comment: You need to do more than just visit. If you want to guarantee your visit counts towards the consecutive visits counter you should conduct an action on each visit. Voting, commenting, posting etc. Heck, that's the whole point of the site anyway.